# Call a class before any other class in Quarkus- Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, quarkus

I am working on Quarkus application, in which I am using Apache camel and in that I am using JAVA DSL way.
I want to call RouteBuilder class after once specific class but RouteBuilder is not allowing that.

```
@Startup
@ApplicationScoped
public class FirstClass {
       void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) {               
             //setting some values which are going to used in RouteBuilder class
       }
}



public class Rout extends RouteBuilder {

   @Override
   public void configure() throws Exception {
      // accessing value which is set on FirstClass but gives null pointer
   }
}
```

Now as you see while application startup I need to call FirstClass before RouteBuilder but everytime I start project RouteBuilder gets called first, how to call FirstClass First while starting apllication?

I have used @Startup, @PostConstrust but no luck, Please help me out as I am new to this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CDI to achieve this. For example:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class FirstClass {
    public FirstClass {
        // Initialise data to be retrieved in the RouteBuilder
    }
}
```

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Routes extends RouteBuilder {

    @Inject
    FirstClass firstClass;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        // Do something with FirstClass
    }
}
```

The camel-quarkus documentation provides some examples on how you can configure your application:

https://camel.apache.org/camel-quarkus/latest/user-guide/bootstrap.html

It's also worth familiarising yourself with how things can be wired together with CDI:

https://camel.apache.org/camel-quarkus/latest/user-guide/cdi.html

https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference

Comment: Yes, this is also a good way to do it. I thought like there will be some annotation which will let class load first like load-on-startup or init-method, but anyways thank you for the answer, this cdi link is good informative.

Comment: In my case I have a  class 'RouteTemplates' which has camel routeTemplates, I have annotated this class with @Startup and @ApplicationScoped and in another class 'SenderRoute' which is a camel routebuilder,  I use the routetemplates defined in `RouteTemplates`. I have even injected `RouteTemplates` in  'SenderRoute' but still I get `Cannot find RouteTemplate with id foobar`. It takes several restarts to have the routetemplates load first, How can I absolutely make sure the `RouteTemplates` loads first?